# How can I run Terminal and Disk Utility at the same time when booted in Recovery Mode / off Recovery Partition in (Mac) OS X

Tags: command-line

In other words how can I run Disk Utility from Terminal when booted in Recovery Mode / off Recovery Partition in recent versions of (Mac) OS X  ?

This was once easy; I've remember I figured it out myself in an old version. (Lion?). There's a solution at [How to open Disk Utility.app through Terminal?](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-open-disk-utility-app-through-terminal.565418/) that fails since around 10.8.

Perhaps it's easier to tell Terminal to reopen after a delay and then open Disk Utility?
The executable open can be found on a bootable partition, so

```
ls -al /Vol*/*/usr/bin/open
```

should show copies.

Why do this?  It's handy to run other things, like `iostat`, `top`, `cp`, `find`, `df`, etc.

Comment: Why don't you use a second Terminal window or a tab? Since Disk Utility.app is more or less a feature-reducing wrapper of `diskutil` with a horrible interface, you should be happy using the command line tool directly.

Comment: Pretty good workaround, @klanomath!  Neither has a great UI.